# Documenting Django REST Framework API for offline usage

Tags: django-rest-framework

There is a number of good documenting tools for Django REST Framework, especially Django REST Swagger: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/documenting-your-api/

All of them are for online usage. Is there a tool to generate offline documentation: PDF or a collection of HTML/CSS-files? Something like http://sphinx-doc.org/ does?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you've the Swagger spec file (JSON/YAML), you can use [Swagger-Codegen](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen#generating-static-html-api-documentation) to generate the static documentation for your REST API.

UPDATE: On May 2018, about 50 top contributors and template creators of Swagger Codegen decided to fork Swagger Codegen to maintain a community-driven version called [OpenAPI Generator](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator). Please refer to the [Q&A](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/blob/master/docs/qna.md) for more information.

Comment: Is it also possible to generate static docs with [Swagger 2.0](http://marcgibbons.github.io/django-rest-swagger/#changes-in-20)?

Comment: yes, swagger codegen works with both the latest version (2.0) and older versions (1.2, 1.1)

Comment: You can take a look at drf-yasg or my answer in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51343394/does-django-rest-framework-have-third-party-apps-to-auto-generate-swagger-yaml-f/51727126#51727126